# Bootstrap Carousel not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've implemented carousel as a slider in my web page. It is working perfectly in firefox and mobile browsers (even chrome). But it is not showing up in chrome.
I can't figure what's wrong. My syntax are:

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel fade-carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000" id="bs-carousel">
  <!-- Overlay -->
  <div class="overlay"></div>

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item slides active">
      <div class="slide-1"></div>
      <div class="hero">
        <hgroup>
            <h1>Nepal&apos;s First</h1>        
            <h3>Nepal&apos;s first portal to buy authentic and verified refurbished Auto-mobiles.</h3>
        </hgroup>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item slides">
      <div class="slide-2"></div>
      <div class="hero">        
        <hgroup>
            <h1>Trusted Sellers</h1>        
            <h3>Buy from our authentic and verified recondition houses across the nation.</h3>
        </hgroup>       

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item slides">
      <div class="slide-3"></div>
      <div class="hero">        
        <hgroup>
            <h1>Tested</h1>        
            <h3>All listed vehicles tested and in well condition.</h3>
        </hgroup>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
/*
Fade content bs-carousel with hero headers
Code snippet by maridlcrmn (Follow me on Twitter @maridlcrmn) for Bootsnipp.com
Image credits: unsplash.com
*/

/********************************/
/*       Fade Bs-carousel       */
/********************************/
.fade-carousel {
    position: relative;
    height: 55vh;
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item {
    height: 55vh;
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-indicators > li {
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #f39c12;
    border-color: #f39c12;
    opacity: .7;
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-indicators > li.active {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
}

/********************************/
/*          Hero Headers        */
/********************************/
.hero {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 3;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.75);
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
          -ms-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
           -o-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
              transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
}
.hero h1 {
    font-size: 6em;    
    font-weight: bold;
color: #d3d3d3d3;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.hero h3{
color:#cccccccc;
}

.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item .hero {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;
       -moz-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
        -ms-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
         -o-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
            transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item.active .hero {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;
       -moz-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
        -ms-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
         -o-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
            transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;    
}

/********************************/
/*            Overlay           */
/********************************/
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #080d15;
    opacity: .2;
}

/********************************/
/*          Custom Buttons      */
/********************************/
.btn.btn-lg {padding: 10px 40px;}
.btn.btn-hero,
.btn.btn-hero:hover,
.btn.btn-hero:focus {
    color: #f5f5f5;
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    border-color: #1abc9c;
    outline: none;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

/********************************/
/*       Slides backgrounds     */
/********************************/
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-1, 
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-2,
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
  height: 55vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-1 {
 background-image: url(../img/homepage-slider/nepalride-banner-1.jpg);; 
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-2 {
  background-image: url(../img/homepage-slider/nepalride-banner-2.jpg);;
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
 background-image: url(../img/homepage-slider/nepalride-banner-3.jpg);;
}

/********************************/
/*          Media Queries       */
/********************************/
@media screen and (min-width: 980px){
    .hero { width: 980px; }    
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
    .hero h1 { font-size: 4em; }    
}
```

Can anyone tell me what to do? I have the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
    at frontend.js:30
```

You can see details on nepalride.com

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle example?

Comment: make sure you have added all the dependencies and try adding some console errors in the `Question` if there are!

Comment: It's working fine for me on chrome.

Comment: @Mr.Arjun Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
    at frontend.js:30 you can check live at nepalride.com

Comment: @StavrosAngelis i also got working on some version of chrome. But most of are not working

Comment: My guess is that you changed something in your js but in the specific pc you have the problem the js file is cached. Try opening the developer tools, click the "Network conditions" tab, click the "Disable cache" option and the refresh your page. If your problem goes away then you have nothing to worry about :)

Comment: @StavrosAngelis I've also tried in PC which hasn't surfed it yet. But same issue is occuring.

Comment: @StavrosAngelis You were right. WHen i disabled cache it worked fine. Thank you.

Comment: @Anon the site is working perfectly fine and there is no issue with the carousel. Have you used `Chart` in your page, the element with `id` `cline` is missing. that's it! I didn't saw any chart in your homepage!

Comment: @Mr.Arjun Thank you. It is working fine after i disabled my cache.

Answer (score 1):

In dom there is no element with the id `cline`. You can avoid the error with this if statement

```
if ($('#cline').length > 0) {
   var cline = document.getElementById("cline").getContext("2d");
   new Chart(cline).Line(lineChartData, {
      responsive: true
   });
}
```

Good luck. 
C

Comment: Where exactly should i place this statement. I tried putting in frontend.js at end of the existing code. But the error didn't go out

Comment: Sincce i wont have any chart in my site. I think its better i remove it right?